# Created function not entering while loop

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I'm trying to test whether a word from a list starts with a letter from a separate list, and create a list with these words. In my created functions, it looks like it's not entering the while loop, as it always returns an empty list.

```
def starts_with(word, chs):
    if word == "":
        return False
    elif chs == []:
        return False
    i = 0
    while i < len(chs):
        x = chs[i]
        if word[0] == x:
            return True
        i+=1
    else:
        return False

def search(words, start_chs):
    i = 0
    ret = []
    while i > len(words):
        x = words[i]
        if starts_with(x, start_chs):
            ret.append(x)
        i += 1  
    if not words:
        return ("not words")

    elif not start_chs:
        return ("not start_chs")
    else:
        return ret

a = ['green', 'grasses', 'frolicking', 'cats', '', 'kittens', 'playful']
b = ['a', 'c', 'g']
new_words = search(a, b)
print(new_words)
```

Comment: How can 0 > `len(words)` ?

Comment: `while i < len(words):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
while i > len(words):
```

With:

```
while i < len(words):
```

You want the index `i` to be *less* than the number of elements in `words`.

After that I get:

```
>>> search(a, b)
['green', 'grasses', 'cats']
```

Incidentally, you could do this in a more Pythonic way using something like:

```
new_words = [item for item in a if item.startswith(tuple(b))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the wrong operator here

```
 while i > len(words):
```

Since, i=0 and len(words)>0 , it never enters the loop.
Change it to

```
 while i < len(words):
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `startswith`:

```
a = ['green', 'grasses', 'frolicking', 'cats', '', 'kittens', 'playful']
b = ['a', 'c', 'g']
new_words = []
for word in a:
    new_words.extend([word for c in b if word.startswith(c)]) 
print(new_words)
# ['green', 'grasses', 'cats']
```

The reason your function always returns empty is that you set `i > len(words)`. At the beginning, `i = 0`, so it always smaller or equal to `words`